# The ) is missing Crystal Report formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to write a simple formula in Crystal reports.  I created a parameter and I am evaluating another field.  Here is an example of my formula:

```
if {COATSEndAssignment.end_date} = "  /  /       :  :   AM" then 
CStr (?custEndDate,"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

I know `{COATSEndAssignment.end_date} = "  /  /       :  :   AM"` is a true expression.

`?custEndDate` is in a date format and I would like to convert it to a string in the format of **"MM/dd/yyyy"**.

When I type the formula above, I get the error **"The ) is missing."** when I try to save the formula.  I have read that there is a possibility I am missing a dll for Crystal Reports, but no where can I find which dll is missing.

I am using Crystal Reports 2011 and I am passing the ?custEndDate parameter in from Visual Studio 2010 and the value is: `#03/21/2014#`.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my formula, or tell me what dll I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curly braces (`{}`) are required for all fields:

```
if {COATSEndAssignment.end_date} = "  /  /       :  :   AM" then 
  CStr({?custEndDate},"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize you had to put curly braces around parameter name, I only thought it applied to table field names.

Comment: Good man,, you just saved me another 2 hours of playing around with brankets